# How to find the maximum of a function with several variables symbolically?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to maximize a function with respect to tau1, tau2, and alpha, and it is like the following:

```
V + β1 τ1 - α τ1^2 - β2 τ1^2 + \τ2 - 2 τ2^2 + α τ2^2
```

I know I can try solve for the partial derivatives with respect to the 3 variables and set them equal to 0, but alpha is linear in this function, and when I tried the following code, it returns a weird solution.

```
Simplify[Solve[D[π1 , τ1] == 0 && D[π1, τ2] == 0, D[π1, α] == 0, {τ1, τ2, α }]]
```

[image]

Since this function involves symbolic variable, V, and beta, I know I cannot go to the numerical route to find maximum, so what should I do then?

Comment: There are syntax errors in your code. You put a comma in front of the last equation instead of `&&`.

Comment: i see thanks! So, it still makes sense to solve for alpha == 0 even thought the partial derivative of the pi1 is linear in alpha?

Comment: are all variables  ($\alpha, \tau_1, \tau_2$) and parameters $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ positive or can they take  negative values?

Comment: yes, all these variables are positive

Answer (score 0):

Looking at and thinking about, one finds

```
ClearAll[\[Alpha], \[Tau]1, \[Tau]2]; Maximize[V + \[Beta]1 \[Tau]1 - \[Alpha] \[Tau]1^2 - 
\[Beta]2 \[Tau]1^2 + \\[Tau]2 -2 \[Tau]2^2 + \[Alpha] \[Tau]2^2 /. {\[Tau]1 -> 
0, \[Alpha] -> \[Tau]2}, \[Tau]2]
```

> {[Infinity],{[Tau]2->Indeterminate}}

Addition. Taking into account the comments of kglr and III done after my answer (French call such behavior  [l'esprit d'escalier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27esprit_de_l%27escalier)), the same result is obtained by

```
ClearAll[\[Alpha], \[Tau]1, \[Tau]2]; Maximize[{V + \[Beta]1 \[Tau]1 \- \[Alpha] \[Tau]1^2 - \[Beta]2 \[Tau]1^2 + \[Tau]2 - 
2 \[Tau]2^2 + \[Alpha] \[Tau]2^2, \[Beta]1 >= 0 && \[Beta]2 >= 0 &&
 V >= 0} /. {\[Tau]1 -> 1/100, \[Alpha] -> \[Tau]2}, \[Tau]2]
```

> $$\left\{
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \{ & 
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  -\infty  & \neg (\text{$\beta $2}\geq 0\land \text{$\beta $1}\geq 0\land V\geq 0) \\
>  \infty  & \text{True} \\
> \end{array}
>  \\
> \end{array}
> ,\{\text{$\tau $2}\to \text{Indeterminate}\}\right\} $$